# How to extract rows in Excel with a given name by function 'xlsread' in Matlab?

Tags: data-mining, matlab, excel

I have 100 Excel sheets of financial statement to extract selected data. For instance, the first sheet is from company A, its 'Total assets' item is in A10, but in the second sheet the 'Total assets' is in A17, the third in A12....

So every financial statement's items have different positions in their Excel sheet. Is there any way I can extract them by specify their name, such as 'Total assets', 'Other earning assets' etc, then I don't need to read their location one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're going to need to read the sheet in, search for the term, then use that location as an anchor.  If, once you find the term, the format is relatively consistent from there, you should be ok.  You might search [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/), but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well - to make it that *you* personally don't have to read is simple. But your program will have to - as excel doesn't feature any shortcuts in this way.

I typically use structures like this:

```
[~,~,table] = xlsread('myfile.xls');
labels = table(:,1);
labels(~cellfun(@ischar,labels))={''}; % just sanitizing
index = ismember(labels,'Total assets');
table_line = table(index,:)
```